# Rails AWS S3 whith paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to use AWS S3 with paperclip but when i load a photo it gives me an error.

[image]

How I can fix it?

Comment: Your error is saying to you that ruby can't create a folder because he doesn't have the rights to write here in your file system. Can you give us more informations about that error ? Like which file does the shown code come from ?

Comment: I have user which has an avatar when I try to load photo I get this error

Comment: You didn't answer my question : what is the name and location of the file in your error ?

Comment: Is this inside `Paperclip` or is it custom code?

Comment: I fix it, lust changed gem 'aws-sdk' on gem 'aws-sdk-v1'